# How to create either Windows or Linux instances using terraform code in jenkins pipeline using parameters?

Tags: git, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

1. In git have to create only one branch ie. master branch where it has linux ami and windows ami mentioned in terraform code.
2. In jenkins while running the pipeline, user should manually enter linux or windows ami parameters but have no idea creating it with single branch.

I have added ec2.tf for windows and linux instance creation in main branch and master branch in git

```
pipeline{
 agent any
     tools{
         terraform 'terra'
     }
stages{
    stage('Git checkout'){
     steps{
         //
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform Init'){
        steps{
            sh label: '', script:'terraform init'
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform apply'){
        steps{
            sh label:'',script:'terraform apply --auto-approve'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

> Expected output is only to create single branch in git and user should manually select the ami id of linux and windows according to their choice when running jenkins pipeline, How can I do this?

**Any advice much appreciated!**

Comment: You need to establish a `parameter` directive in the pipeline, and then pass them as inputs to declared variables in Terraform.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard Thanks for the answer, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

## This works

```
 agent any
     tools{
         terraform 'terra'
     }
 parameters{
   choice(name:'ami', choices: ['Linux','Windows'])
   choice(name:'Actions', choices:['apply','destroy'])
}
stages{
    stage('Git checkout'){
     steps{
         //
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform Init'){
        steps{
            sh label: '', script:'terraform init'
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform apply'){
        steps{
            sh label:'',script:'terraform ${Actions} -var name="${ami}" --auto-approve'
        }
    }
  }
}
```